# How to use asynchronous iterator using aiter() and anext() builtins

Tags: python-3.x

I have gone through the documentation of [aiter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#aiter) and [anext](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#anext) (New in version 3.10). But not understanding how to use them.

I have the following program:

```
import asyncio

async def get_range():
    for i in range(10):
        print(f"start {i}")
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        print(f"end {i}")
        yield i

class AIter:
    def __init__(self, N):
        self.i = 0
        self.N = N

    def __aiter__(self):
        return self

    async def __anext__(self):
        i = self.i
        print(f"start {i}")
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        print(f"end {i}")
        if i >= self.N:
            raise StopAsyncIteration
        self.i += 1
        return i

async def main():
    async for p in AIter(10):
        print(f"finally {p}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

How can I use `aiter` and `anext` builtin here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like with the regular synchronous `iter` and `next` builtins, you rarely need to use the new builtins directly. The `async for` loop in `main` calls the `__aiter__` and `__anext__` methods of your class already. If that does all you want, you're home free.

You only need to explicitly use `aiter` and `anext` if you are writing code that interacts with an asynchronous iterator in some way not directly supported by a `async for` loop. For instance, here's an asynchronous generator that yields pairs of values from the iterable it's given:

```
async def pairwise(aiterable, default=None):
    ait = aiter(aiterable)                  # get a reference to the iterator
    async for x in ait:
        yield x, await anext(ait, default)  # get an extra value, yield a 2-tuple
```

If you loop on `pairwise(AIter(10))` in your `main` function, you'll find that it now prints tuples of numbers, like `finally (0, 1)`. Before each tuple, you'll see two sets of the `begin` and `end` lines printed by the iterator class, one for each value that ends up in the paired result.